# How do I access the Twitter API from my website to display my latest tweet?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, react-boilerplate

**Background:**

I'm using the react-boilerplate to build a personal website, and I would like to display my latest tweet in the footer. I do not want the embedded card, only the tweet itself (similar to the [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en) extension).

This appears to be what I am looking for:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

**Question:**

How is my website supposed to authenticate with the Twitter API, without including the authentication data in the website's codebase?

Should I have an app in the middle that processes the requests, or is it possible for my website to directly retrieve my latest tweet each time a user accesses my page?

Thanks